# CSS transform of div shouldn't affect content

Tags: html, css

I have outer div section and within outer div i have inner div section on mouse hover i want only outer div section should be transition and inner div section text should not transit should remain constant somebody help me out in achieving it.

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/zeYZL/56/

**HTML**

```
  <div class="outer">
        <div class='inner'>
            <p>inner text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .outer
{
  width:283px;
  height:298px;
  float:left;
  background:#101820;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:Lato;
  font-weight:900;
  font-size:3.4em;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:298px;
  transition:all 0.3s ease;
}
.outer:hover
{
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.03);
  width:283px;
  height:298px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:#ffa300;
}
```

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/zeYZL/57/ ?

Comment: exactly Thank you so much @Vitorinofernandes

Answer (score 5):

when a `transform` is applied to the parent the child gets affected automatically and even adding `transform: none` to the child will have no effect. So, the best approach is to add the `transform` to a absolutely positioned sibling

- I have used a `:pseudo` element `:after` to add a `background-color` and added `scale` to it which will prevent the child from getting scaled

```css
 .outer {
   width: 283px;
   height: 298px;
   float: left;
   color: #fff;
   position: relative;
   font-family: Lato;
   font-weight: 900;
   font-size: 3.4em;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 298px;
 }
 .outer:after {
   content: '';
   background: #101820;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
   z-index: -1;
 }
 .outer:hover:after {
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
   -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
   transform: scale(1.03);
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: #ffa300;
 }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class='inner'>
    <p>inner text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Spot on. Just for info (maybe you could add it into the answer too), when a transform is applied to the parent the child gets affected automatically and even adding `transform: none` to the child will have no effect. So, the best approach is to add the `transform` to a absolutely positioned sibling (like you've done).

Answer (score 0):

Along with other css add the following for inner div.

```
 .inner:hover {
   -webkit-transition: none !important;
   -moz-transition: none !important;
   -o-transition: none !important;
   -ms-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
```

}

You can mix it with jquery too.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say here. This wouldn't solve the OPs problem. And I seriously don't get the need for jQuery.